Terminating wires into circular connector panel mount screw terminals properly
This circular panel mount has screw connectors that I'm unfamiliar with, and I'm having a hard time finding out online how to terminate my cables properly in them.

I'm used to crimping ferrules onto my stranded wire before screwing them into the usual screw terminals, but these terminals seem to have an unexpected orientation. What is the proper method to terminate wires into them?

Data sheet link? What's the advantage of those screw terminals over a solder connection,  with some nice shrink tubing? They look very inconvenient and possibly costly. The screw appears to bear directly on whatever you stick in the hole.

https://sg.rs-online.com/web/p/industrial-circular-connectors/1246675
The datasheet is practically useless...

Please link the data sheet.

Okay. Made by some unknown outfit. So why not use the solder 131-6371? I also see more sensibly designed M21 connectors from other makers with a right-angle grub screw or regular screw that can accept a crimped ferrule.

I have encountered these in the field.  They do completely destroy hookup wire with a crimped ferrule.  I did not like the result at all.  Even more concerning, I have seen this style of terminals on IEC 60320 cord end connectors.  Does not inspire confidence at all. Avoid if you can.

I suggest you avoid these entirely. Not only are they not consistent with common Chinese M21 connector designs, which are either solder type or can accept a ferrule that drops in where the screw on these is, and have a right-angle fixing fastener (and often extra plastic insulation around the pins) but they are made by some unknown outfit and bear an unconscionably high markup.
If you really want to use this particular supplier, there is a solder version 131-6371. Or stick crimped ferrules in the holes and make sure you have enough space around the part and enough insulation that it is safe. Hopefully the pins are solid enough in the molding that they won't rotate easily (which I doubt).

Have to agree, they don't look particularly robust. +1

The datasheet says termination type solder/screw/crimp, so it looks like you have options.
With the screws you risk weakening the wire and having a failure at some point. It is the easiest way though, just strip the wires, stick them in the holes and tighten the screws until snug.
Crimping just looks like it would be difficult to do well with the pins so close together. Unless they mean crimping a ferrule onto the wires and tightening the screw down on that, then you've got the problem of the wires sticking out sideways.
Soldering is probably the best option, you just have to be careful to not overheat it and melt the plastic housing. Take the screws out, strip and tin the wires and insert them into the pins, heat the pin with your iron and add solder at the hole.
